# Vlc 3.0.0 не показывает

Tags: android, потоки-данных, vlc

Взяв пример [отсюда](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-3/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java.shtml), добавил ссылку на видео в устройстве `nexus.mp4`, запускаю - работает.

Добавил зависимость `compile 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:3.0.0'` и заменил стандартный плеер на этот `org.videolan.libvlc.media.MediaPlayer`, но видео не показывает, что я упустил?

[Ссылка на мой проблемный код](https://github.com/vaszol/StreamPlayer/tree/5597d03d8dd90352e708787dd9ee963834a6f15a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наткнулся на вот такой [пример](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples/blob/master/java_sample/src/main/java/org/videolan/javasample/JavaActivity.java) и все пошло.